# android: how to destroy item from listview

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I have a `Listview`. Each items has multiple fields such as title, image, description and image. I have extended the `Baseadapter` and hence populated the `listview`. The task is to self delete the item. i.e. delete the item from ListView after the number of seconds (given time)

I tried to do by attaching `timer` with items but it throws error and also I found that is not the proper way. please help me to solve this problem.

Lets say the data are as follows

```
Title ¦ Description ¦ Image ¦ time
alpha1 ¦ this is the description of alpha 1 ¦ images/abc.jpg ¦ 56858
alpha2 ¦ this is the description of alpha 2 ¦ images/abc.jpg ¦ 63
alpha3 ¦ this is the description of alpha 3 ¦ images/abc.jpg ¦ 3600
```

here the item has to die (die in a sense that it deletes from the list) after the given seconds

Comment: By default the listview loads only the data that can be accommodated on the mobile device's screen.

Comment: thanks for the comment amalBit. may be i couldn't deliver my quest so i have updated the question.

Comment: Your question is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a pointer to the objects of list. Then you run following:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myListViewArrayOfItems.remove(index);
        myListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}, numberOfSeconds);
```

Also you could have method declared in the adapter `removeItem(final int index)` where you run

```
myListViewArrayOfItems.remove(index);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If the numberOfSeconds is random and the removal operation needs to be available for cancel:

```
public class RemoveRunnable implements Runnable {

    public interface RemoveListener {
        void onItemRemoved(int index);
    }

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mIndexToRemove;
    private RemoveListener mListener;

    public RemoveRunnable(BaseAdapter adapter, int index, RemoveListener listener) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mIndexToRemove = index;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void run() {
        mAdapter.removeItem(mIndexToRemove);
        mListener.onItemRemoved(mIndexToRemove);
    }

    public void updateIndex(int removedIndex) {
        if (removedIndex < mIndexToRemove) {
            mIndexToRemove--;
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private List<RemoveRunnable> mRunnables = new ArrayList<RemoveRunnable>();

private void removeItem(final int index, final int delay) {
    Runnable runnable = new RemoveRunnable(myAdapter, index, this);

    mRunnables.add(runnable);

    mHandler.postDelayed, delay);
}

private void cancelAllRemovals() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}

@Override
public void onItemRemoved(final int index) {
    mRunnables.remove(index);

    // Update rest indexes
    for (int i=0; i < mRunnables.size(); i++) {
        mRunnables.get(i).updateIndex(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Niko. but the problem is time to destroy each item is different. item 1 will die in 5sec then item 2 in 10mins and item 3 in 5mins. the time is not fixed. and when also if i refresh the list to get more data, i would have to delete all defined timer.

Comment: Okay, then the code will be little bit more complex, I do not have access to IDE at the moment, so cannot do the code from scratch by memory, but I can update some key points to the answer which could show you the way.

Comment: thanks for your effort @Niko . i will try this answer and get back to you. thanks